# Not returning the proper ID

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So I am trying to modify student participation, by them collecting "points" in a class. This is done in the attendance table, where each student has an attendance ID as the PK.

Here's my issue: cursor c, which should return the ID from the attendance table, is instead returning numbers like "1," "2," and "3," which seem specific to (maybe) the app running, instead of querying the database and returning the ID there. I know this for a fact as I have taken the database file, and checked it with a database browser. The ID in the database is correct. The cursor isn't retrieving the proper ID.

```
TADADataDbHelper dbreadhelper = new TADADataDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase dbread = dbreadhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final long meeting = bundle.getLong("meeting");

    String sql = "select * " +
                " from "  + Meetings.TABLE_NAME +
                " , " + Attendance.TABLE_NAME +
                " , " + Student.TABLE_NAME +
                " where " + Meetings.TABLE_NAME+"."+Meetings._ID + "= '" + meeting + "'" +
                " and " + Student.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENTID + "=" + Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENT +
                " and " + Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_PRESENT + "=1" +
                " and " + Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_MEETING + "=" + Meetings.TABLE_NAME+"."+Meetings._ID;

    Cursor c = dbread.rawQuery(sql, null);

    String[] fromfields = {Student.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENTNAME,Student.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENTNAME,Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_PARTICIPATION,Student.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENTNAME};
    int[] tofields = {R.id.addpartbutton,R.id.studentnametext,R.id.studentpointstext,R.id.subpartbutton};

    try {
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapt2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.participationlistitem, c, fromfields, tofields);


        adapt2.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("Meedz","Entered");
                if(!(view instanceof Button))
                    return false;

                Log.i("Meedz","Went on");

                final Button controller = (Button) view;

                final Cursor c = cursor;

                if (controller.getId()==R.id.addpartbutton)
                    controller.setText("+");
                else
                    controller.setText("-");

                final long attid = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("attendance._id"));
                final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("student.studentname"));

                controller.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        TADADataDbHelper dbreadhelper = new TADADataDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
                        SQLiteDatabase dbread = dbreadhelper.getWritableDatabase();

                        if (controller.getId()==R.id.addpartbutton)
                        {
                            Log.i("Meedz","Adding "+attid+name);
```

this last line is what should display the attendance id. It is displaying simple numbers, while this is not the case in the actual database.

```
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            Log.i("Meedz","Substracting "+attid);
                        }


                    }
                });


                return true;
            }
        });


        ListView mylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.participationlist);
        mylist.setAdapter(adapt2);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I discovered, for anyone else's benefit..

If you have an _ID, the cursor will attempt to use it to index. So then, what should you do? In my case, it was easy because I had more than one _ID (because I was doing a join) and I simply left one of them as _ID, and gave the rest names. I then referred to that name later, and it was retrieving the proper ID from the database. This wasn't quite easy to figure out; it took a couple of days. I hope this helps whoever's reading it.

My select statement changed as follows:

```
String sql = "select " +
                            Student.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENTID + COMMA + 
                            Student.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENTNAME + COMMA +
                            Student.TABLE_NAME + "." + Student._ID + " " + COMMA +
                            Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_MEETING + COMMA +
                            Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_PARTICIPATION + COMMA +
                            Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_PRESENT + COMMA +
                            Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENT + COMMA +
                            Attendance.TABLE_NAME + "." + Attendance._ID + "newattendanceid" + COMMA +
                            Meetings.COLUMN_NAME_CODE + COMMA +
                            Meetings.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + COMMA +
                            Meetings.COLUMN_NAME_MAJOR + COMMA +
                            Meetings.COLUMN_NAME_SECTION + COMMA +
                            Meetings.TABLE_NAME + "." + Meetings._ID + " newmeetingid" +
                " from "  + Meetings.TABLE_NAME +
                " , " + Attendance.TABLE_NAME +
                " , " + Student.TABLE_NAME +
                " where newmeetingid = '" + meeting + "'" +
                " and " + Student.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENTID + "=" + Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_STUDENT +
                " and " + Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_PRESENT + "=1" +
                " and " + Attendance.COLUMN_NAME_MEETING + "= newmeetingid";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I think 'attid' is just index in the result because you called getColumnIndex. So you need to call actual value-retrieving functions like cursor.getLong(...).

Comment: No, I don't think so. This is the code for attid.
`final long attid = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("attendance._id"));`

Comment: Sorry for not being helpful. What I can tell you is you had better test SQL statement first rather than coding. In usual SQL browsers, you can execute sql statements. So you can test and see the result using tools.<br> If I understood right, you checked the state and value in DB file. If you didn't try to see the result of your select statement, I recommend trying it with tool first.

Comment: Thanks! I checked, and the sql statement returns what's expected. I'm not sure what's going on, or why the cursor is using the _ID as an index.